# Junit passing multiple parameters to rest service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I have a rest controller like bellow :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    GlobalResponse createDeal(@RequestBody Deal deal,@RequestBody Owner owner) {

// code here

}
```

I use Junit and Mockito for my test :

```
@Test
    public void createDeal() throws Exception{
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/Deal/create").content("\"deal\":{\"dealNumber\":\"DA001\"},\"owner\":{\"id\":1}").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());
    }
```

I cant past multiple parameters to the controller service , how can I avoid this ?

Comment: why don't you test `createDeal(..)` method by supplying `Deal` and `Owner ` instances directly?

Comment: I didn't get you , can you please explain more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to pass multiple arguments annotated with [@RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation. The argument annotated with this annotation holds the whole request body and it can't be split into multiple.

What you can do is to have a wrapper to hold your `Deal` and `Owner` objects and you can pass that wrapper as a single request body argument.

For e.g.:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private Deal deal;
    private Owner owner;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

And your controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    GlobalResponse createDeal(@RequestBody Wrapper wrapper) {

// code here

}
```

Hope this makes sense.